# Retrieve the events from a SharePoint calendar using REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, calendar

I have the rest endpoint for accessing the sharepoint calendar from my internal network at work. It looks like this:
https://teamsites.{COMPANY}.com/sites/{SITE_URI}/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle({TITLE-OF-CALENDAR})/items

When I do an authorized GET request to the above url, it gives me a list of 4 events from the calendar, but the dates are kind of random. What is the endpoint I need to specify in order to retrieve all of the events for the current month?

Also, I'm guessing that the reason I'm only getting 4 events per request is because of some pagination thing that I'm not handling... if you know how to retrieve all the events in one request, that would be a bonus.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The events for a current month could be retrieved via the following CAML query:

```
<Where>
   <DateRangesOverlap>
      <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
      <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
      <Value Type='DateTime'>
          <Month />
      </Value>
   </DateRangesOverlap>
</Where>
```

For that matter [`GetItems` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListGetItems) could be utilized as demonstrated below:

```
var query = `
<Where>
   <DateRangesOverlap>
      <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
      <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
      <Value Type='DateTime'>
          <Month />
      </Value>
   </DateRangesOverlap>
</Where>`


getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'TeamCalendar',query)
.done(function(data){
     var items = data.d.results;
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
{
    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml  
               }
    };
    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}
```

But there is one **limitation** with this approach, neither REST nor CSOM/JSOM APIs do **not** support expanding for recurring events (*it means only a single event item will be returned for a recurring event*). Refer those requests for a more details:

- [Provide CSOM and REST API for recurring calendar events](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147117-provide-csom-and-rest-api-for-recurring-calendar-e)
- [Add support for recurring events in the REST API](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/9065308-add-support-for-recurring-events-in-the-rest-api)

For that scenario legacy SharePoint Web Services comes to the rescue, in particular [Lists Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists(v=office.12).aspx).

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve events for a current month and expand recurring events ([SPServices library](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) is utilized here):

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "TeamCal",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Location' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
        "</ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query>" +
            "<Where>" +
                "<DateRangesOverlap>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
                        "<Month />" +
                    "</Value>" +
                "</DateRangesOverlap>" +
            "</Where>" +
            "<OrderBy>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" +
        "</Query>",
    CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions>" +
            "<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>" +
            "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
        "</QueryOptions>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

            var $node = $(this);
            var eventTitle = $node.attr("ows_Title");
            console.log(eventTitle);

        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I was able to look at the api link you sent and your detailed examples to create a solution in my code. It appears that the possible recurring events problem wasn't an issue in my use case.